# Deployed images not updating on Heroku and Node.js

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am new to heroku and Node.js. I am facing following issue.

I have deployed some images on heroku. Then I edited some images locally and deployed again those images on heroku. But newly deployed images are not taking effect. I am still seeing old images.

I came to know that we need to run following commands on Ruby on rails
heroku run rake assets:clean
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace

But I do know how to do the same on Node.js env.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a browser cache problem. You should try to clear your browser's cache.

If you're using chrome go to the three bars in the top right, then go to 'History'then click 'Clear browsing data...' and just select the 'cached images and files' checkbox. This will also undo any saved passwords on your browser so be careful.

**NOTE:** Could you give more details? Are the urls in the source code of the page with "new" images showing the urls for the "new" images, or the "old" ones?

Also as a reminder, node is not like Rails. It is not really a framework; it's a wrapper for javascript. Are you using express, or some other node.js framework?

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I tried to open it in different browsers but still it is showing same. Actually urls of the images is same. I did not change the image name or url. I just edited the image itself and uploaded it again. I am using angular-fullstack, yo, grunt and express also on development system. Then do grunt build which generates dist folder. I push this dist folder to heroku system.

Comment: I think this is an angularjs problem. I'm not expert on angular, but you should look up cache busting, basically the process of adding a randomized value to a URL every time it's saved / loaded to prevent caching. It seems like there's a lot of stuff out on google that could help.  $scope.apply(), also seems to be a recurring theme with the problem you are describing.